# Subdomains re-directing to Ghost Blog installed in site root

Tags: node.js, subdomain, cpanel, ghost-blog

I have [Ghost](https://ghost.org/download/) installed in my site root, and another instance installed in a subdomain. Ghost was installed with Softaculous and both of these instances are working correctly. (Seperate databases and ghost instances.)

However, other subdomains now return a ghost 404 page instead of displaying their contents.

My file structure looks like:

```
public_html
  ├── subdomain                 - This displays the ghost 404 page from my root installation    
  │   ├── index.html            - I want it to display this index.html file
  │   └── assets             
  ├── ghost subdomain           - This is working correctly
  │   ├── content
  │   ├── core            
  │   └── etc                
  ├── content
  ├── core
  ├── config.js
  ├── Gruntfile.js
  └── etc
```

My main site's `config.js` file production settings look like:

```
    production: {
    url: 'http://courtneyspurgeon.com',
    mail: { removed }
    },
    database: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
    host: 'localhost'
    user: 'removed'
    password: 'removed'
    database: 'removed'
    charset: 'utf8',
    insecureAuth: true,
    socketPath: '/tmp/mysql.sock',
        },
        debug: false
    },
    server: {
        // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
        port: '65506'
    }
},
```

I suspect I need to change the server settings, or scope part of this somehow, but I'm not sure how.

If it helps, my main site is: http://courtneyspurgeon.com/ (running ghost)

And an example of a subdomain that is not working: http://blog.courtneyspurgeon.com/ (not running ghost, but returning the parent site's 404 content.)

**I welcome suggestions regarding what files or settings I should look at, even if you don't have a specific answer.**

Comment: Try some exorcism, I've heard it helps against ghosts :P

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at your Apache config files.  You will need to have a config file for courtneyspurgeon.com that directs traffic to Ghost and another that is listening on blog.courtneyspurgeon.com that directs traffic to public_html/subdomain/index.html.  Right now it sounds like Apache is not being told that it needs to handle your courtneyspurgeon.com and blog.courtneyspurgeon.com traffic differently.

If you are using Ubuntu I would have a look in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.  And if you are on CentOS take a look in /etc/httpd/sites-available and /etc/httpd/httpd.conf.